# How to show a gif image in angular mobile app

Tags: html, angular, typescript, gif

I have a component `spinner.component.html` like this:

```
<div *ngIf="show">
    <img [src]="loadingImage" *ngIf="loadingImage" width="120px" height="120px"/>
</div>
```

And a controller `spinner.component.ts` like this:

```
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() loadingImage: string;
  @Input() show: boolean = false;
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.name) 
      throw new Error("Spinner must have a 'name' attribute.");

    this.spinnerService.register(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.spinnerService.unregister(this);
  }
}
```

And finally I have a spinner service `spinner.service.ts`:

```
export class SpinnerService {

  private spinnerCache = new Set<SpinnerComponent>();

  constructor() { }

  register(spinner: SpinnerComponent) {
    this.spinnerCache.add(spinner);
  }

  unregister(spinnerToRemove: SpinnerComponent) {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner === spinnerToRemove) {
        this.spinnerCache.delete(spinner);
      }
    });
  }

  show(spinnerName: string) {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner.name === spinnerName) {
        spinner.show = true;
      }
    });
  }

  hide(spinnerName: string) {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner.name === spinnerName) {
          spinner.show = false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

In my `app.component.html` I declare my spinner:

```
<spinner name="mSpinner" loadingImage="assets/spinner.gif"></spinner>
```

This is working perfectly fine in desktop browsers but when I try it on mobile browser I cant see the gif, instead this is what I get:

[image]

But if I write the `src` attribute directly in the tag image like this:

```
<img src="assets/spinner.gif" *ngIf="loadingImage" width="120px" height="120px"/>
```

works in both desktop and mobile browsers. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What browsers and versions (desktop and mobile) have you tried exactly?

Comment: In desktop Google Chrome (version 68.0.3440.106). In mobile Google Chrome (version 68.0.3440.91).

Comment: I'd try a couple more desktop browsers (and maybe more mobile browsers) before diagnosing this as `desktop != mobile`problem when there's a chance it can be `a specific browser` problem.

Comment: In desktop works in IE11, Opera and Firefox but not in mobile version.

Comment: It's strange, but try < spinner name="mSpinner" [loadingImage]=" 'assets/spinner.gif' ">< /spinner> (remove spaces)

Comment: @Eliseo Works on desktop but not in mobile. Same issue.